# php variable variables and PHP global variables

Tags: php

I am working on a javascript application that uses ajax to request data from a SOAP API by the intermediary of a PHP script.
my ajax requests are times GET and other times POST.
to configure the API request i created a function that, based on the HTTP method used, construct the configuration array and returns it.
this is my function :

```
function configureApiRequest($source, $collection){
    $configuration = array();
    foreach ($collection as $key){
        if(strlen(${$source}[$value]) > 0){
            $configuration[$key] = ${$source}[$key];
        }
    }
    return $configuration;
}
```

and this is how i invoke it :

```
$configuration = configureApiRequest('_GET', array('conditions', 'orderBy', 'limit', 'skip', 'marketingGroupFilter', 'returnFields'));
```

as you can see in the function, i used PHP variable variables to determine if the method used if GET or POST. but i got the error :

> Undefined variable: _GET
>   what is the problem ?

Comment: Read the big red warning at the bottom of the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: oh god, thanks and sorry, i should delete this question